# Make Table/iframe disappear with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with an iframe inside. I want a script that will make the iframe(or table) disappear gradually in about 2 seconds. Thank you to anyone who can help.

```
<table align="center" id="table" border="1">
<tr>
<td>      
<iframe width="853" height="480" src="..." frameborder="0" id="iFrame" allowfullscreen>    </iframe>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: `$('table').fadeOut(2000);` since you have tagged this jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to attach it to? An Onclick/Mouseover..?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#SELECTOR HERE').click(function() {
        $('#table').fadeOut(2000);
    });
});
```